# Template function gets defined as deleted

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I was trying to modify Anthony William's code in C++ Concurrency in Action (2nd edition) and faced some errors. Details as below:

Here is Anthony Williams' original code:

```
template<typename Func>
std::experimental::future<decltype(std::declval<Func>()())> spawn_async(Func&& func){
    std::experimental::promise<decltype(std::declval<Func>()())> p;
    auto res=p.get_future();
    std::thread t(
        [p=std::move(p),f=std::decay_t<Func>(func)]() mutable{
            try{
                 p.set_value_at_thread_exit(f());
            } catch(...){
              p.set_exception_at_thread_exit(std::current_exception());
            }
         });
   t.detach();
   return res;
}
```

I wanted to modify the code above so that spawn_async would accept any callable rather than only those with empty parameters list.

This is my code:

**spawn_async.hpp**

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
auto spawn_async(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    std::promise<std::result_of_t<Func(Args&&...)>> prom;
    auto res = prom.get_future();
    auto lambda = [p = std::move(prom), f=std::decay_t<Func>(func)](auto&&... a) mutable
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                    p.set_value_at_thread_exit(f(a...));
                            }
                            catch (...) 
                            {
                                    p.set_exception_at_thread_exit(std::current_exception());
                            }
                    };              
    auto async_func = std::bind(lambda, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::thread t(async_func);
    t.detach();
    return res;                     
}
```

I have replaced `std::experimental::future`and `std::experimental::promise`in Anthony's code with `std::future` and `std::promise` instead.

This is the code I used to test it:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "spawn_async.hpp"

int func(int a, double d)
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    auto ret = spawn_async(func, 1, 2.4);
    std::cout << ret.get() << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following errors with g++ (7.2.1):

```
g++ --std=c++17 test.cpp spawn_async.hpp
In file included from spawn_async.hpp:3:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional: In instantiation of ‘std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(const _Functor&, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int, double}; _Functor = spawn_async(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = int (&)(int, double); Args = {int, double}; typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type = int]::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)>; _Bound_args = {int, double}]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:878:38:   required from ‘typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = spawn_async(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = int (&)(int, double); Args = {int, double}; typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type = int]::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)>&; _BoundArgs = {int, double}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind<spawn_async(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = int (&)(int, double); Args = {int, double}; typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type = int]::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)>(int, double)>]’
spawn_async.hpp:23:29:   required from ‘std::future<typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type> spawn_async(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = int (&)(int, double); Args = {int, double}; typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type = int]’
test.cpp:11:37:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/functional:529:59: **error: use of deleted function ‘spawn_async(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = int (&)(int, double); Args = {int, double}; typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type = int]::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)>::<lambda>(const spawn_async(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = int (&)(int, double); Args = {int, double}; typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type = int]::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)>&)’
  : _M_f(__f), _M_bound_args(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)**
                                                           ^
In file included from test.cpp:2:0:
spawn_async.hpp:12:64: **note: ‘spawn_async(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = int (&)(int, double); Args = {int, double}; typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type = int]::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)>::<lambda>(const spawn_async(Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = int (&)(int, double); Args = {int, double}; typename std::result_of<Func(Args&& ...)>::type = int]::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:**
  **auto lambda = [p = std::move(prom), f=std::decay_t<Func>(func)](auto&&... a) mutable**
                                                                ^
spawn_async.hpp:12:64: error: use of deleted function ‘std::promise<_Res>::promise(const std::promise<_Res>&) [with _Res = int]’
In file included from spawn_async.hpp:1:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/future:1077:7: note: declared here
       **promise(const promise&) = delete;**
       ^~~~~~~

(etc etc etc)
```

I don't understand why the compiler reports spawn_async function as being implicitly deleted when it is exactly the function I am trying to instantiate.

Also it says I am trying to use the deleted copy constructor of std::promise class, but in my code I am calling the move constructor while using C++14 lambda init capture functionality.

I don't understand why I am getting these errors and how to modify my code to make it behave the right way. Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why the compiler reports spawn_async function as being implicitly deleted when it is exactly the function I am trying to instantiate.

spawn_async is not deleted, std::promise copy costructor is (as the error shows). The problem is in the lines

```
auto async_func = std::bind(lambda, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
std::thread t(async_func);
```

[std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) will copy the lambda there; moreover, bind returns a copy constructible objects only when both the lambda and its bound arguments are(*). In this case, the lambda is movable-only due to its promise member. Instead, it should be

`std::thread t( std::bind( std::move(lambda), std::forward<Args>(args)...)` );

or just

```
std::thread t( std::move(lambda), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
```

and let thread do the binding on its own ( it will decay-copy as bind does but with no added std::bind overhead )

(*) more precisely, bind holds members of decay_t'ed type constructed via perfect forwarding

Comment: @Madhusudhan moreover, take a look at the edit; you can let std::thread do the binding for you ...